# entering two formulas in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to get a count of how many requests are coming in.  It should be the number of active requests that are greater than 7 days but less than 30 days...

so basically, I need to combine these two formulas below:

```
=IF(IF(ISBLANK([Activated Date]),0,(1. *(TODAY()-[Activated Date]))) > 7,TRUE,FALSE)
```

and the other one I want to add to it is:

```
=IF(IF(ISBLANK([Activated Date]),0,(1. *(TODAY()-[Activated Date]))) < 30,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: use the `and` formula.

Comment: ooooh ok....is it with quotation marks

Comment: this is what i entered, but it gave me and error

Comment: =IF(IF(ISBLANK([Activated Date]),0,(1. *(TODAY()-[Activated Date]))) < 60,TRUE,FALSE) and IF(IF(ISBLANK([Activated Date]),0,(1. *(TODAY()-[Activated Date]))) > 30,TRUE,FALSE)

Comment: Use [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/and.php) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>This is a Wiki because I shouldn't get rep but it *should* get an answer.</sub>

As already mentioned in the comments by KronoS:

```
=AND(IF(IF(ISBLANK([Activated Date]),0,(1. *(TODAY()-[Activated Date]))) > 7,TRUE,FALSE),IF(IF(ISBLANK([Activated Date]),0,(1. *(TODAY()-[Activated Date]))) < 30,TRUE,FALSE))
```

In fact, you don't need the `IF(~,TRUE,FALSE)` part at all. If all you put is a test condition, it returns TRUE or FALSE by default.

```
=AND(IF(ISBLANK([Activated Date]),0,(1. *(TODAY()-[Activated Date]))) > 7, IF(ISBLANK([Activated Date]),0,(1. *(TODAY()-[Activated Date]))) < 30)
```

Comment: +1 for the added value of the last part of the answer.